# Buildfire: Image is not displaying after placing working code in source code for some reason

Tags: image, buildfire

I wanted to know why my image isn't showing up in the Buildfire platform when i place the code into the source area.....I've tested it on everything else and it works perfectly...dreamweaver and everything.... Need help to help get the image to show up in buildfire.  The code i am using is below:

```
<p class="bf-wysiwyg-hide-app bf-wysiwyg-top"><img src="blob:https://pluginserver.buildfire.com/890db794-346d-4428-be1f-aa8dd5f5efdc" style="display: none;" onload="typeof buildfire !== 'undefined' &amp;&amp; buildfire.dynamicBlocks.execute(this);" data-type="dynamic-expression" /></p>
<div id="bf_mce_layout_2" class="bf-wysiwyg-top bf-wysiwyg-hide-app" data-bf-layout="%7B%22id%22%3A%22bf_mce_layout_2%22%2C%22cssUrl%22%3A%22layouts/bf_mce_layout2.css%22%2C%22htmlUrl%22%3A%22layouts/template_a.html%22%7D" data-layout-name="bf_mce_layout_2"><!-- This template should not be changed once is live -->
<div class="bf_mce_img-container"><img src="https://dallasexaminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Preparing-for-Legislative-Session.jpg" onclick="buildfire.actionItems.execute(JSON.parse(unescape(this.getAttribute(&quot;data-execute&quot;))), ()=&gt;{})" data-bf-image="%7B%22originalSrc%22%3A%22https%3A//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/imageserver.prod/71e97b33-4374-11ec-9fe6-12a56cc33887/karen-bass.jpg%22%7D" data-execute="%7B%22action%22%3A%22linkToApp%22%2C%22instanceId%22%3A%22665ce2b8-7ce6-4cb5-bbfc-282dc22cdd6c-1651251310477%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Current%20News%22%2C%22iconUrl%22%3A%22https%3A//pluginserver.buildfire.com/plugins/60/resources/icon.png%22%2C%22queryString%22%3Anull%2C%22deeplinkId%22%3Anull%7D" /></div>
<div class="bf_mce_copy">
<h1>Current News</h1>
<p class="bf_mce_caption">Check out the current news from The Dallas Examiner today by clicking the button below</p>
</div>
<button class="bf-btn bf-btn-primary" onclick="buildfire.actionItems.execute(JSON.parse(unescape(this.getAttribute('data-execute'))), ()=&gt;{})" data-execute="%7B%22title%22%3A%22Current%20News%22%2C%22iconUrl%22%3A%22https%3A//pluginserver.buildfire.com/plugins/60/resources/icon.png%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22linkToApp%22%2C%22instanceId%22%3A%22665ce2b8-7ce6-4cb5-bbfc-282dc22cdd6c-1651251310477%22%2C%22queryString%22%3Anull%2C%22deeplinkId%22%3Anull%7D">Current News</button></div>
<p class="bf-wysiwyg-top bf-wysiwyg-hide-app">&nbsp;</p>
<style class="bf-wysiwyg-top bf-wysiwyg-hide-app" data-layout-name="bf_mce_layout_2">
#bf_mce_layout_2 * > span{
    color: currentColor;
}
#bf_mce_layout_2{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 .5rem 1rem rgba(77, 77, 77, 0.5);
}
#bf_mce_layout_2 .bf_mce_img-container{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
#bf_mce_layout_2 .bf_mce_img-container img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
#bf_mce_layout_2 .bf_mce_copy{
    padding: 1rem;
}
#bf_mce_layout_2 .bf_mce_copy h1{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}
#bf_mce_layout_2 .bf_mce_copy .bf_mce_caption{
    font-size: .75rem !important;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
#bf_mce_layout_2 .bf_mce_copy p{
    line-height: 1.5;
}
#bf_mce_layout_2 button{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    min-width: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
}</style>
```

[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oterl.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAJs2.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIJKs.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM7uY.jpg)

I placed in a code that works perfectly in dreamweaver into the source code area of Buildfire and for some reason the image is not showing up.  I need help with this  The code is below:

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to run just fine, screenshot below:
[image]

Maybe a problem retrieving the image? I'd check the network traffic in Safari or Google Chrome and see if the image being requested or not.

If it is being requested then check if you're getting any status code errors. If it is not being requested try adding more information.